# An way to manually fail backup for azure webapp for testing of script

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am writing a powershell script to checks the failed backup in azure and send and email when any backup fails my script is almost complete but I want to test it by manually failing the backup is there any way to make the backup fail for azure webapp so that I can check my script is working fine or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manually fail the backup, you could follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the web app in the portal -> `Backups` -> `Configure` -> configure it with a container in a storage account.

[image]

2.Navigate to the storage account in the portal, delete the container which you configured.

[image]

3.Then back to the `Backups` in the web app, click the `Backup`, after a while, refresh and you will find it failed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wang. can it be done by the changing firewall setting in storage account?

Comment: @S.k Yes, I test it just now, it will also fail. First, configure the backup, then open the firewall of the storage account.